# Numerical approximation of derivaties

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, numerical-methods

I am taking a course on deep learning and I a have a good understanding of High School math.
In the course they gave a formula saying that the derivative of a function $f(x)$

$f'(x) = \frac\lim{h\to0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $ (formula 1)

Which is the first principle of derivatives

Then they gave another formula saying that in numerical approximation the first principle don't work well, The formula was
$f'(x)=\frac\lim{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ (formula 2)

They also said that the order of error in the first method is of $h$ and for the second is $h^2$

Which is much better assuming h is less than one.

I don't understand how this works because take $f(x)=x^3$ the triangle considered when we take $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$ will be smaller than the triangle considered when taking  $(x-h,f(x-h))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$ so shouldn't formula 1 give a better approximation of slope than the second. Since bigger triangles tend to make more errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}h=3x^2+3xh+h^2$$

vs.

$$\frac{(x+h)^3-(x-h)^3}{2h}=3x^2+h^2$$

See which is the most accurate ?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the error term (using Taylor) is of the form 
${ 1 \over 2} h f''(\xi)$ whereas for the second it is
${1\over 4} h (f''(\xi_+)- f''(\xi_-))$ and if $f$ is smooth then 
$|f''(\xi_+)- f''(\xi_-)| \le L|\xi_+- \xi_-| \le L |h|$, which is where the $h^2$ comes from.

Roughly speaking the even terms tend to cancel.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy to see if you draw a convex curve, and join the three points at x, x+h, x-h, and also draw the tangent at x.